# How to debug a code block in Pycharm Scientific View

Tags: debugging, pycharm

I have code blocks that begin with `# %%`.

I would like the debuger to start inside a particular code block and then pause at my breakpoint.

It just runs through the entire script by default.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported at the moment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29672

Perhaps Jupyter notebooks in PyCharm can be a good alternative. They do support independent cell debugging.